# I'm try to make game using unity and my Jump functionality not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make simple 2D game following tutorials when I did same thing as tutorial my jump functionality not working and left and right move functionality working please help me below I attached my source code and relevant screen shot

my player class

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D _rigid;
    //variable for jump
    [SerializeField]
    private float _jumpForce = 5.0f;
    [SerializeField]
    private LayerMask _grondLayer;
    private bool _resetJump = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        _rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Movement();
    }

    void Movement()
    {
        float move = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        _rigid.velocity = new Vector2(move,_rigid.velocity.y);
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && IsGrounded()==true)
        {
            Debug.Log("jump");
            _rigid.velocity = new Vector2(_rigid.velocity.x,_jumpForce);
            StartCoroutine(ResetJumpNeededRoutine());
        }
    }

    bool IsGrounded()
    {
        RaycastHit2D hitInfo = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.down, 0.6f, _grondLayer);
        if(hitInfo.collider != null)
        {
            if(_resetJump==false){return true;}
        }
        return false;
    }

    IEnumerator ResetJumpNeededRoutine()
    {
        _resetJump = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        _resetJump = false;
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct way to implement the jump mechanism on 2d character.

```
_rigid.AddForce(new Vector2(0, _jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

Comment: @ManojMadushanka it will work now, If works consider green tick

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably the LayerMask you selected `Ground` layer to be ignored therefore `IsGrounded` function will return false.

What you wanna do is select the layers you'd like your Raycast to ignore (All except `Ground` I assume) in the unity editor then give it another go.